# JS Recursive Function Issues

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I can't seem to get this to repeat whenever past and current are the same (it's a new quote generator).

```
    function random() { // random number 0-9
      var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
      return number;
    }

    var past = [0];     // array of past quotes

    function writer() { // on button click for new random quote
      var current = random();
      past.push(current);
      function checker() {
        if (past[past.length - 2] === past[past.length - 1]) {
          current = random();
          checker();
        } 
      }
      checker();
    }
```

Comment: The comment on your `random` function is wrong, it returns 0..8. Anyway, is there a reason for this brute force approach? It may be easier to fill an array with possible answers, pick one at random and then remove it from the array for the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the random() catch, and while that would definitely work, I'm also very curious about what I did wrong. There's no real reason to the brute force beyond that's just how I like to roll.

Comment: Ah – you are changing `current` but that does not change the value in your array. The line `past.push(current)` pushes its *value* immediately, and then forgets where it came from. So afterwards changing `current` does not automagically change its last pushed value.

Answer (score 0):

*Rekursiv geht meistens schief* (sorry no English for that)

You did not change the last value if the condition is true:

```
var past = [-1]; // impossible value;

function writer() { // on button click for new random quote
  var current = random();       // get a first random
  past.push(current);           // add this to past array
  function checker() {
                                // check last two values
    if (past[past.length - 2] === past[past.length - 1]) {
      current = random();       // if equal, get a new random;
      checker();                // re-call - BUT -
                                // as there' actually no change to past,
                                // we're in an infinite loop.
    }                           
  }
  checker();
}
```

Change:

```
var past = [-1]; // impossible value;

function writer() { // on button click for new random quote
  var current = random();       // get a first random
  past.push(current);           // add this to past array
  function checker() {
                                // check last two values
    if (past[past.length - 2] === past[past.length - 1]) {
      current = random();       // if equal, set a new random even to past
      past[past.length - 1] = current;
      checker();                // re-call 
    }                           
  }
  checker();
}
```